# Enabling OverlayFS on Ubuntu 20.04 makes GNU GRUB selection pop up at boot

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, overlayfs

I followed [this great tutorial on how to enable overlayfs](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/10/protecting-ubuntu-root-filesystem/), basically just involves setting the file:

```
/etc/overlayroot.conf
```

to

```
overlayroot_cfgdisk="disabled"
overlayroot="tmpfs:swap=1,recurse=0"
```

Then rebooting. It work great, but theres some strange side effect that at boot, GNU GRUB pops up and asks me what I want to do:

```
GNU GRUB version 2.04
---------------------

*Ubuntu
 Advanced options for UIbuntu
 UEFI Firmware Setting

---------------------
Use up and down arrow to select which entry is highlighted.
Press enter to boot the selected OS.....
```

I have tried looking at my BIOS boot order settings, did not help.
If I disable OverlayFS, the request for the selection goes away.

How can I have OverlayFS without the request to select option at boot with GNU GRUB?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [overlayroot and grub2 - grub menu always shows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046979/overlayroot-and-grub2-grub-menu-always-shows)

Comment: Yes brilliant that solved the issue, thank you!